# Sonar Gerrit plugin not posting comments when changedLinesOnly == true

Tags: jenkins-plugins, gerrit, sonar-gerrit

I'm using Sonar Gerrit plugin for Jenkins and it works fine in its default mode (**changedLinesOnly == false, isNew == false**).

However, when I'm enabling **changedLinesOnly == true**, all issues vanish, even those that were added in the Gerrit patch (e.g. unused variable).

Is this a bug, or perhaps I'm missing something?

Components versions:

**Jenkins:**: 2.95

**Gerrit:**: 2.13.4

**Sonar-Gerrit:** 2.1

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Max. You can e-mail developers (me) directly using the e-mail provided on the plugin wiki page. To help you with troubleshooting I need 1) your pipeline code or screenshot of your plugin settings; 2) name of the file with an issue ignored; 3) lines from your sonar-report file regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the issue here with:

```
Jenkins     : 2.73.1
Gerrit      : 2.14.3
Sonar Gerrit: 2.2.1
```

This worked nicely before (I don't remember the versions)... it seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I've raised an issue in sonar-gerrit github: https://github.com/aquarellian/sonar-gerrit-plugin/issues/21

Comment: Github seems to be dead, raised an issue in Jenkins Jira: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49639

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed in v2.3 of SonarGerrit plugin. Tatiana, thank you for fixing this!